# How can i position a background image to the top left and bottom right of a html element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background, background-image

I got a paragraph and i wish to have a visible "marker" to show the start and end of the paragraph to the user.

I got no problem to show the backgroundimage on the upper left, but i do not know how to position the background-image to the lower right end. Here my css for positioning the image to the upper left:

```
p[class] {
    background-image: url("../../image/my_image.gif");
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I am not looking for a solution using additional html elements!!! It needs to work using css only! Due to the fact that the paragraph has set pseude-before and pseudo after elements i am not able to use them here. So the question is:

**How can i position a background image to the top left and bottom right of a html element without using additional html elements but css only (and no pseudo elements)?**

Comment: suggestion try { left: 0px ; top:0px; }

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cyrille is near but wrong. it needs to be `background-position: right bottom;`

in general - its posible to use numeric values. 
So for `background-position: right bottom;` you can also write `background-position: 100% 100%;` and `background-position: left top;` would result in `background-position: 0 0;`

also take a look at the W3C specs on this: `http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-position`

to sree's comment of above: this is completely wrong, `left: 0px ; top:0px;` does refer on positioning of the HTML element itself when using `position:relative` or `position:absolute`

edit:
if you like to use multiple backgrounds you can note it als follows:

```
p[class] {
    background-image: url("../../image/my_image.gif"), url("../../image/my_image.gif");
    background-position: left top, right bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

look at http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds for cross browser support

greets

tom

Answer (score 4):

If browser support is not a problem for you, you could do with CSS3 multiple backgrounds: http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/

Answer (score 1):

What about trying `background-position: bottom right` instead of `left top` ?

Comment: i want the image (as a marker) to be shown on both ends of the paragraph, this will only switch it to the other side

Comment: Oh sorry, I misinterpreted. Then you should look into what’s called *generated content*, namely using `:before` or `:after`.

Comment: i am not able to use those pseudo elements because the paragraph has set them already and i would overwrite those otherwise, did forget to mention this and have updated my question

Comment: OK, then which browsers are you targeting? You could use CSS3 multiple backgrounds, but they're not supported everywhere.